# sed is outputting the correct file in the terminal but no substitutions have taken place in the new file

Tags: text-processing, sed

When I run my shell script below from the command line, it outputs the copied file to the screen and I can see the substitutions have taken place correctly, however within the new file it has created it still shows the original file contents from the original.html - what am i doing wrong with the saving aspect to a new file?

```
# other relevant vars above #
cp original.html MobileApp/www/index.html

sed  -E'' "s#MOBILE_APP_API_URL#\"$mobile_app_api_url\"#g;
    s#MOBILE_APP_MEDIA_URL#\"$mobile_app_media_url\"#g;
    s#MOBILE_APP_ENVIRONMENT#\"$environment\"#g" MobileApp/www/index.html
```

// note 
if I use sed -i at the start of the line this works as expected but for portability reasons I do not want to use the -i argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would go with

```
sed -E -e "s#MOBILE_APP_API_URL#\"$mobile_app_api_url\"#g" \
       -e "s#MOBILE_APP_MEDIA_URL#\"$mobile_app_media_url\"#g" \
       -e "s#MOBILE_APP_ENVIRONMENT#\"$environment\"#g" \
       original.html >MobileApp/www/index.html
```

The `-E` flag doesn't take an argument, and with multiple `-e` sections we're able to break the command line into readable chunks.

We may skip the `cp` completely since we process the source file and write directly to the target file using a redirection.

Comment: Awesome you obviously know what you are talking about ;-) 
(i read your bio lol)